# Presever-order=true does not work in selenium-grid

Tags: selenium, testng, selenium-grid

```
@BeforeTest
@Parameters({"selenium.host", "selenium.port", "selenium.browser", "selenium.url" })
public void startServer(String host, String port, String browser, String url) throws Exception {      
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium(host, Integer.parseInt(port), browser, url);
        selenium.start();
    }
```

testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="SL-Grid" parallel="false">

    <parameter name="username" value="test" />
    <parameter name="password" value="test1" /> 

<test name="SL-Chrome" preserve-order="true"> 
    <parameter name="selenium.host" value="localhost"></parameter> 
        <parameter name="selenium.port" value="5555"></parameter> 
        <parameter name="selenium.browser" value="*googlechrome"></parameter> 
        <parameter name="selenium.url" value="http://properurl:8080/"></parameter> 
        <classes>
            <class name="com.TestBase" /> // Base class where all generic methods, setUp and tearDown methods present
            <class name="com.Login"> // Login related methods and inherit TestBase
                <methods>
                    <include name="loginPage" />
                    <include name="signIn" />
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class name="com.Page1">
                <methods>               
                    <include name="clickLinkA" />
                    <include name="isTextBoxXXXPresent" />
</methods> </class></classes></test>

<test name="SL-Firefox" preserve-order="true"> 
    <parameter name="selenium.host" value="172.16.4.21"></parameter> 
        <parameter name="selenium.port" value="5556"></parameter> 
        <parameter name="selenium.browser" value="*firefox"></parameter> 
        <parameter name="selenium.url" value="http://properurl:8080/"></parameter> 
        <classes>
            <class name="com.TestBase" /> // Base class where all generic methods, setUp and tearDown methods present
            <class name="com.Login"> // Login related methods and inherit TestBase
                <methods>
                    <include name="loginPage" />
                    <include name="signIn" />
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class name="com.Page2">
                <methods>               
                    <include name="clickLinkB" />
                    <include name="isListBoxXXXPresent" />
</methods> </class></classes></test>

</suite>
```

When i run the suite it should invoke startServer() from TestBase -> loginPage() and SignIn() from Login -> clickLinkA() and isTextBoxXXXPresent() from Page1. But manytimes system first invokes mathods from Page1 class and so gets failed (since signIn is not invoked).

Can any one please tell me where i am wrong here. Or any other better way to design. or any alternate for preserve-order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be issue in TestNG which you can report to TestNg guys. But to overcome your issue, you can include your login & Signin method in your BeforeTest or call it in your test Method in this case clickLinkA.
Hope this solves your prblm.

Comment: Thank Varun.
Yes, as per your suggestion by inserting loginPage & signIn code into startServer() works fine. But i want to keep all login related code into com.Login class. So i have created a object in startServer() and called loginPage() and signIn() as below:
LoginPage lp=new LoginPage(); lp.loginPage(); lp.signIn(username, password);  
//by writing the above code i can now delete <class name="com.Login"> block from testng.xml
 
Personally i want to live with testng suite instead of creating object and calling methods. but no choice as preserve-order="true" is not working in my case.

Comment: whatever you are doing that is the correct way. YOu have to always keep your reused code as a method in one common class. And use it by creating an object. Advantage being if your login logic changes u just have to change at one place rather than multiple.

Comment: yes Varun.. now all the methods are getting executed but the order of executing is still a concern... Page2(Search section) always getting executed before Page1(Landing Page)..

Comment: If your page2 methods depends on page1 test execution? As you Page1 and Page 2 classes are in 2 different tests they will execute in different threads.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using dependsOnMethods to make sure that one test that depends on another runs after it.  You can also set a numeric priority, where the lower numbers run first.  The default for priority is 0, so you would only need to set this for tests to run after those that do not have a priority set.